# PCB trace inductance

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, inductor, pcb-fabrication, inductance

I am planning to do a high current (200 A+) PWM in a PCB and I am afraid the PCB traces inductances will be a huge problem... so I have some questions:

1. How may I calculate the trace inductance?
2. The wider the trace the less the resistance, but does this work also for inductance?

I know there will be problems with the frequencies but I just want to get the feeling...

Comment: Sounds interesting and dangerous. What's the edge rate or rise time of your pwm signal going to be?   Also you don't really just measure trace inductance, inductance is measured in a loop so you have to account for your trace and it's return path to get the full picture.  Trace inductance is affected by width, but also more so by the distance between the two connection points.  I'd guess you'll want a nice fat trace and return plane kept as short as possible.

Comment: It's a H-Bridge controller for fighting robots :D
I still dont have all the details, so I am still figuring all the problems I will have...

Comment: I just checked an online trace width calculator. For 200 A, allowing 20 C temperature rise, with 2 oz copper, they're recommending a 6 inch trace width. Two calculators roughly agreed on this value, but one has a note that the calculation is based on tables that only cover up to 35 A current, so it may be inaccurate. I don't find, in a quick search, any tables or calculators that cover 200 A.

Comment: I'm thinking if you can give us some more info about what you're *really* trying to do, we might come up with some ideas about how to do it without having to switch 200 A at high speed.

Comment: I am very thankful about all the effort, but my question was just about the inductance, I am curious about how it behaves according the trace's measures...not just related to this problem, but just to know for future things as well :D

Comment: Just to make things clear, the plan for now is a N-MOSFET H-Bridge for a DC Motor, holding at least 200A.
I know the results you got from this calculators are based just in resistance, but my doubts are how the inductance behaves as I change the traces geometry....if I make the traces wider, the resistance decreases, but how does the inductance behaves in this case? Will it decrease as well or it will increase and I have to findo some middle term and compensate the impedance with a capacitor?

Comment: Don't use a printed circuit board for 200A circuits! Not everything has to be on a printed circuit board. For example, your car's battery isn't connected to the starter via a circuit board.

Comment: Trace impedance is unlikely to be a problem for any frequency you can achieve with 200A MOSFETs. Motor impedance is also going to be a much bigger factor. For something of this size, you'll probably want to bolt/clamp the FETs to copper busbar rather than solder.

Comment: I saw some people having problem with the PCB inductance, the MOSFETs all exploded just because the traces, there was not even a motor connected...

Comment: @Kaz there are many H Bridge controllers out there that can handle 200+A , there is no way to make it fit an airplane or a robot if it is not modular as a PCB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are your specs for resistance of the copper?  If you can meet the resistance specs the inductance problem WILL BE REDUCED to the same range of impedance as the resistance for flat copper.

If the Length, l, to diameter, d, ratio is known, you can calculate the Inductance, L, series resistance, Rs and the aspect ratio l/d is related to Q = L/Rs for a given conductor material.

Let's consider the impedance for copper at 1 MHz.

- aspect ratio = l/d = 5   10  125  1250  12,500
- Impedance quality =  Q  = L/Rs  2.6  4    8    12      16
- where Impedance, Z = ZL + ZR

For flat copper tracks the aspect ratio is quite different and lower Q but you will need very thick copper to reduce the ohmic loss @ 200 A.

I would suggest you use thick braided wire from the board edge and make the copper loss and inductance less than the Ron of your switches and not rely on copper traces. Thick tracks would make the cost of etched copper loss too high (unless you consider solid busbars added to board...)

Comment: That's exactly why I am asking this...I wanted to know if a copper braid or exposing solder mask to add solder to the traces will lower the resistance AND inductance or will decrease one and increase the other...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, as Kaz said in a comment, "Don't use a printed circuit board for 200A circuits!", because the resistive effects will be very challenging to deal with.

Second, as pjc50 said, "Trace [inductance] is unlikely to be a problem for any frequency you can achieve with 200A MOSFETs"

That said, I'll answer your more specific question,

> if I make the traces wider, the resistance decreases, but how does the inductance behaves in this case?

Your intuition is correct, a wider trace **reduces** the inductance.

You can see this in the approximating formulas for microstrip parameters, which I copy from [here](http://www.technick.net/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=util_pcb_imp_microstrip).

[image]

\$L_0=C_0Z_0^2\$

In these formulas, *Z<sub>0</sub>* is the characteristic impedance, *C<sub>0</sub>* is the capacitance per meter of trace, and *L<sub>0</sub>* is the inductance per meter of trace. *W* is the trace width, *H* is the trace height above the ground plane (assumed infinite), and *T* is the thickness of the copper. Be sure to check the source web page before using them, as I'm not sure of the units and assumptions used.

Since C<sub>0</sub> and Z<sub>0</sub> both have *W* (the trace width) in the denominator, we can see that L<sub>0</sub> must decrease as *W* increases.

Before using these formulas, realize that they're meant to approximate the behavior over a range of width and height parameters that are likely to be used in real circuits. They are not necessarily accurate in extreme cases, like you're likely to need for 200 A. However the general trends are correct.

Also, there are many alternative approximation formulas for the microstrip parameters, some more complicated than what's given here (in order to give accurate approximations over a wider range of parameters). The ones given in Johnson and Graham have separate formulas for W > H and W < H, which may get them closer to reality for your situation.

Comment: He could be shunting dozens of MOSFETS for all we know

Comment: @Richman, I don't see the connection between your comment and my answer.

Comment: "Don't use a printed circuit board for 200A circuits!"  Current can be load shared on a circuit board.

Comment: @Richman, The two first paragraphs are more advice than facts. I'd have added "...unless you know exactly what you are doing". But I wanted to quote Kaz to give him credit for having the thought first.

Comment: _"Since C0 and Z0 both have W (the trace width) in the denominator, we can see that L0 must decrease as W increases."_ - Is that correct? From what I can tell C0 increases with increasing width (which makes sense). W is in the denominator of the ln() term and thus the "main" denominator gets smaller with increasing W.